# Run docker container with official postgres image, failed to access the container

Tags: postgresql, image, docker, containers, psql

I wanted to run postgres database in docker container.
I pulled the newest image of postgres:

```
docker pull postgres
```

And started container out of it:

```
docker run --rm --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -d -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

After that I tried to access the postgres:

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres
```

And connection failed:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I don't understand why?

[EDIT]
I tried it on Windows 10 Pro with Docker Toolbox and it fails, however on Ubuntu 18.04 works fine.

Comment: Are you using Docker Toolbox, perhaps on a Windows 7 system?  Did you wait a minute or so for the database to start up?

Comment: Yes, I use Docker Toolbox on Windows 10 and I waited more than one minute :/

Comment: I tried on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and it works perfectly fine, perhaps it is the matter of VM for Docker Toolbox on Windows.

Comment: If you're using Docker Toolbox, nothing will be `localhost`; you need to find the Docker VM's IP address with `docker-machine ip` and give that to `psql` where you have `localhost` now.

Comment: Thank You, that's what I just figured out :) You are right.